# Android app crashes while posting answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I just came across one more issue which is being happened due to the unavailability of network connection.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Open app and make sure its having network connection ON. (Ohh yes it will show you alert otherwise and prompt you to make internet connection ON).
2. Select any question and navigate to answer selection
3. Turn off Network connection
4. Click on <kbd>Add an answer</kbd>.
5. As its says, enter atleast 30 characters
6. Click on either <kbd>Preview</kbd> or <kbd>Submit</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! We're currently working on making the app app gracefully handle network failure, so this should be fixed soon.

Comment: @Kasra cool....

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I think its resolved already so decorate it with status-completed :)

Comment: For me, it happens constantly, when posting the answer. The answer is posted, so the app must crush afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed a while ago, as you commented.